# Regex operations on Javascript functions

Tags: javascript, regex, sed, grep

I'm trying to find function names in Javascript and insert the following code

```
var functionName = arguments.callee.toString().substr('function '.length);
functionName = functionName .substr(0,functionName .indexOf('('));
console.log(functionName);
```

This will write the name of the function to the console as it's called. I am not having much luck with this. I've been trying variants of this with sed.exe:

```
sed "{/function/ s/$/\var ownName = arguments.callee.toString().substr('function '.length);ownName = ownName.substr(0,ownName.indexOf('('));console.log(ownName);/}" *.js
```

This is just in the format `sed "/elephant/ s/$/\&castle" *.js`

Anyone have any idea how I can send what I'm appending to the next line, rather than on the same line as function? Also, how can I imlement the following (but in sed.exe) to avoid anonymous function and eval functions??

```
grep -Eho "^s*function w+" *.js | sort
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Beware that `Function#toString` does **not** necessarily return a string version of the function (esp. not on mobile browsers) and has never been standardized. Also be aware that using `arguments.callee` will slow down your code *dramatically* on some browsers. (Like 10X dramatically.) Fine for instrumentation of debug stuff, as long as you're aware of the issues.

Comment: Bear in mind that JavaScript is too complex to be perfectly parsed with regex, although you can come up with something that works "well enough".

Answer (score 0):

Adding `\n` into the replacement string works for GNU sed.    I changed the regex you have for grep into `^[[:blank:]]*function \w\+` for sed and changed the condition of your `s` statement to that, and it worked properly.  Here's the whole command in bash syntax:

```
sed "/^[[:blank:]]*function \\w\\+/ s/\$/\\nvar ownName = arguments.callee.toString().substr('function '.length);\\nownName = ownName.substr(0,ownName.indexOf('('));\\nconsole.log(ownName);\\n/" *.js
```

Comment: `sed` doesn't understand `\s` so you'll need to use `[[:blank:]]` and you're missing an extra backslash on a newline. As an alternative to doing all that escaping, you can use single quotes around the whole thing and `\x27` instead of the single quotes in the replacement text. By the way, that's not Bash syntax. That same command would work in almost any shell. The syntax is specific to `sed`.

Comment: @Dennis: I fixed the ``\s`` and missing escape bugs; I used double quotes since the original RE did.  It turns out the syntax is specific to GNU sed; I put that it was bash syntax because it doesn't work as is in tcsh.  It probably works in any non-csh shell.